# What is the proper syntax to impl default for accountid?

Tags: substrate-node-template

For the following struct, I store the author of a post as the AccountId of the content creator which requires a default value. I cannot for the life of me figure out the proper syntax to handle this as nothing seems to work. Could I get a proper example please?

```rs
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Encode, Decode, scale_info::TypeInfo)]
struct Post<AccountId> {
    author: AccountId,
}

impl<AccountId> Default for Post<AccountId> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Post: "default address here",
    }
}
```

I have tried using string, string.into(), etc. Could I please get the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

First, be careful with default `AccountId`s. It was [removed from Substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10403), so make sure you understand the need for a default and the risks and that you choose it wisely.

It depends which `AccountId` you've chosen, but it's usually some variant of the [MultiAddress](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ded44948e2d5a398abcb4e342b0513cb690961bb/primitives/runtime/src/multiaddress.rs#L26). Assuming that it's a 32 byte AccountId, you'd need to provide a `[u8; 32]`.

Note that the SS58 *address* includes a prefix, the 32 byte AccountId, and a checksum, so it actually has more information than just the AccountId. This is handy for address validation and UI rendering.

Comment: I do. The accountid needs to be a part of the post struct tho. The workaround is nightmarish, especially on the frontend. Its simpler, easier, and more efficient to include as part of the struct. And because this is the case, I need to impl default for an accountid. So, would that look like this:

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

?

Comment: Using `0x0…` is a hack, not a proper fix. If there is no `AccountId` then maybe `Post` should use `Option<AccountId>`?

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example please? I'm specifically not sure where to add the option tag.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your circumstances it could be better to use the `OnEmpty` of your `StorageValue` or an `OptionQuery`.

Your Rust syntax looks off to me:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Encode, Decode, scale_info::TypeInfo)]
struct Post<AccountId> {
    author: AccountId,
}

impl<AccountId> Default for Post<AccountId> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { author: "default address here" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what using option looks like?